# Array prints memory address despite Override

Tags: java

Now, I want it to only print what it says, without the memory address as well. How would I achieve that?

```
    public Telefonnummer[] getTelenummer() {

    Telefonnummer[] tnummer = new Telefonnummer[nummerarray.size()];
    nummerarray.toArray(tnummer);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tnummer) );


    return tnummer;
```

}

Is the constructor and:

```
    private static void kundSök() {
    System.out.println("...? ");
    String namn = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (kunderna.containsKey(namn)) {
        for (String k : kunderna.keySet()) {
            Kund kund = kunderna.get(k);
            System.out.println(kund);
            System.out.println(kund.getTelenummer());
```

After i have added a person to the ArrayList etc it gives me an output of:

Sam wasdfgn
[123456: efdg]
[LTelefonnummer;@28d93b30

The last part, memory address bit, is the part I want to get rid of.
Yet again, how do i achieve that?

Edit: I tried to Override, but it did not do anything at all. Could there be another problem?

Comment: Give `Telefonnummer` a `toString()` override!

Comment: not memory address, it is hashcode, do what Hovercraft suggested

Comment: The number is not the memory address, it is the Object's hashCode().

Comment: It sounds like you may have nested arrays? What happens if you try Arrays.deepToString()? It's really hard to tell from your code what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The [default behaviour for `toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is to print the type name (as `L` followed by the type name), followed by `@` and the hexString of the hashCode (which by default is the memory address for the object).

To change this, override the `toString` method for your `Telefonnummer` class.

```
public class Telefonnummer {
  private String nummer;
  ...
  @Override public String toString() {
    return "Dial " + nummer + " for a good time";
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea that hashCode uses the memory address is a historical artefact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236615/does-object-tostring-or-object-hashcode-ever-give-the-memory-address-of-the-obje

Answer (score 0):

Guava library has Joiner which can be used for that. See https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

String str = Joiner.on(",").join(list);

You also have to have working toString function on class for elements of the list